# Is $2^{n+1} \leq a + b \leq 4^n$ when $4^n - 1 = ab \quad \text{; with } n,a,b \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality

$4^n - 1 = ab \quad \text{; with } n,a,b \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } a, b \mid 4^n - 1$

**Is this inequation always true: $2^{n+1} \leq a + b \leq 4^n$ ?**

I already know that:

$4^n - 1 = \left(2^n\right)^2 - 1 = \left(2^n - 1\right) \left(2^n + 1\right)$

If it would be:

$a = \left(2^n - 1\right)$ and $b = \left(2^n + 1\right)$

then $a + b = 2^{n+1}$.

If it would be:

$a = 1$ and $b = 4^n - 1$

then $a + b = 4^n$.

But what about the other cases?

Comment: This is a minimization problem. You are lucky as for this problem it doesn't matter whether you do it over the reals or natural numbers. So you can use basic calculus to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to do a proof by checking certain cases, as you're trying, is not sufficient as there's an infinite # of them. Instead, you need to use a more general technique. First, though, I assume by $\mathbb{N}$ you mean integers which are positive, i.e., it doesn't include $0$, since otherwise your inequalities are not always necessarily true (e.g., you could get $4^{0} - 1 = 0 = ab$, so $a = b = 0$, but $2^{0 + 1} = 2 \le 0 + 0 = 0$ is not true).

As you stated, you're trying check if it's always true that

$$2^{n+1} \leq a + b \leq 4^n \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

given that

$$4^n - 1 = ab \implies 4^n = ab + 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note $4^n - 1$ is odd, so $a$ and $b$ are odd integers. Also, due to the symmetry in $a$ and $b$ in the problem, assume WLOG that $a \ge b$. First, checking the right side of the inequality, you want to see if

$$a + b \le 4^n = ab + 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

If $b = 1$, then \eqref{eq3A} becomes $a + 1 \le a + 1$, which is obviously true. Next, if $b \ge 3$, you then have

$$ab + 1 \ge 3a + 1 = 2a + a + 1 \ge 2a + b + 1 \gt a + b \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This shows \eqref{eq3A} also holds in that case too. Update: As [bjorn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/570684/bjorn93)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632357/is-2n1-leq-a-b-leq-4n-when-4n-1-ab-quad-text-with-n-a-b/3632414?noredirect=1#comment7465277_3632414) below states, it's easier to see this since $a + b \le ab + 1$ is equivalent to $(a - 1)(b - 1) \ge 0$.

Next, note all odd perfect squares are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, but since $4^n - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, this means you have that $a \neq b$. Since have assumed $a \ge b$, this means, using \eqref{eq2A}, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a - b & \ge 2 \\
(a - b)^2 & \ge 4 \\
a^2 - 2ab + b^2 & \ge 4 \\
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 & \ge 4ab + 4 \\
(a + b)^2 & \ge 4(ab + 1) \\
(a + b)^2 & \ge 4(4^n) \\
(a + b)^2 & \ge 2^{2(n+1)} \\
a + b & \ge 2^{n+1}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This shows the left side of the inequality in \eqref{eq1A} is also always true.

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you! I was to much focused on the single cases.

Comment: Regarding the first inequality, $a+b\leq ab+1$ is equivalent to $(a-1)(b-1)\geq 0$ which is true for $a,b\geq 1$.

Comment: @bjorn93 Thanks for the feedback. I didn't notice that simplification originally, but you're right, so I've added this to the answer, with appropriate attribution to you.